# Flutter some default styling on new project

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm starting on flutter, already sorry if it's a noob question

Basically started with a new project and there I am getting an already applied theme

How to remove this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just remove the MaterialApp widget and directly return the Text widget and don't forget to pass the textDirection in the Text widget - textDirection: TextDirection.ltr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have a completely black screen because you don't have a [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget.

The [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget is screen that will be displayed on your display.
You can add your `Text` widget in the `body` property of your `Scaffold`

```dart
return const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
       body: Text("Hello")
    )
);
```

Comment: I think he want to completely remove the Material theme, which comes in the MaterialApp widget

Comment: Oh I might have misunderstood his question. If that's the case, you can override the `theme` property in the MaterialApp to create your own custom Material Theme, and create custom widgets to have an app that doesn't feel too material-like.

Comment: OMG. Thank you. I had done this before but lost the pace in few months and was struggling now. Thank you this fixed my issue.